# Clone single div contents with the same class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone only contents of the clicked div's with the same class but different ID's.  Have tried several answers with no luck. 
Have tried this as well
    $(this).next('.pick').clone().appendTo('#four');

Here is what I have as an example.

```
<div id="one" class="pick">
One
</div>
<div id="two" class="pick">
Two
</div>
<div id="three" class="pick">
Three
</div>
<div id="four" class="pickfour">
Four
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pick").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
        $(function(){   
$(".pick", this).clone().appendTo('#four');
    });  
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4fk94xzz/ kindly check this if this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for 2nd `Domready` code, and simply use `$(this)` as a selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pick").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).clone().appendTo('#four');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="pick">
  One
</div>
<div id="two" class="pick">
  Two
</div>
<div id="three" class="pick">
  Three
</div>
<div id="four" class="pickfour">
  Four
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want clone contents, you only get innerHTML of it.

```
$("#four").append($(this).html());
```